# Error when sending mail to an external mail server from Postfix on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I just installed Postfix. i have not yet done any configuration on it. Each time I try to use it to sendmail from another application, it keeps telling me that COnnection was refused from the ip I want to connect to. This is the error I get

[root@localhost /]# telnet mail.abuse.org
Trying 69.43.160.153...
telnet: connect to address 69.43.160.153: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

COuld someone please help me the problem

Comment: `telnet your_ip 25` or `telnet your_domain 25`

Comment: I did that and it's refusing connection. What I what to know is why I cannot connect to any other network apart from localhost

Comment: Can you please run 'postconf -n' and post the results? This will show us any non-default settings in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP may be blocking outbound connections to port 25, it's surprisingly common.  If you find you can connect to the rest of the world on just about any other port than 25, suspect this.

Answer (score 0):

By default, IP tables might be blocking your connection. Try:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

And the retry to telnet to your ip on port 25 like this:

```
telnet localhost 25
```